# How to open a new project from existing code base in visual studio and save it? So I can open that saved project next time

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have source code for a C based project, I want open it in Visual studio for editing.

In visual studio, 
**File -> New -> Project From Existing Code** 
which helps me to open a new project from existing code.

How can **I save this project and reopen it** again after sometime?

Please help me on this...

Comment: Have you tried File -> Save All option?

Answer (score 0):

When we open a new project from **File -> New -> Project From Existing Code**, a **ProjectName.sln** file is getting created. 
We have to use this file to reopen this project again. File-> Open -> Project/Solution

Thanks for your support.